# Verificar si un valor esta en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de muchos objetos como el siguiente

```
let arrayProductos = [
        {"producto": "90060181", "cuotas": "2"},
        {"producto": "90160763", "cuotas": "6"},
        {"producto": "93650002", "cuotas": "3"},
        {"producto": "33350088", "cuotas": "12"},
    ]
```

y por otro lado tengo una variable `productoEjemplo=93650002`

Como puedo hacer para obtener las cuotas de `productoEjemplo` sin la necesidad de recorrerlo con un `for` ?

Comment: Sin cambiar tu estructura ... no hay forma. Puedes usar un `filter( )` u algún otro *embellecedor*, pero seguirás teniendo que recorrer los elementos hasta encontrar el buscado.

Comment: Como dice Juanjo filter es un enbellecedor.Pero si manejas muchos datos y lo que que quieres es velocidad te recomendaria hacer un for clásico y comparar tiempos que seguro le ganas de esta manera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), este método te devuelve todos los elementos de un array que cumplan un criterio específico

```js
const productoEjemplo=93650002;

let arrayProductos = [
  {"producto": "90060181", "cuotas": "2"},
  {"producto": "90160763", "cuotas": "6"},
  {"producto": "93650002", "cuotas": "3"},
  {"producto": "33350088", "cuotas": "12"},
];

const productos = arrayProductos.filter(element => element.producto == productoEjemplo); // Filtrar los elementos, obteniendo cada elemento y comprobando si su propiedad "producto" es igual a productoEjemplo

console.log(productos);
```